# Finding quality flag in Sentinel-5P data to filter by

Tags: google-earth-engine

I would like to filter S-5P data to show only data with clouds less than 5% using Google Earth Engine. I'm working with [Sentinel-5P NRTI NO2: Near Real-Time Nitrogen Dioxide](https://developers.google.com/earth-engine/datasets/catalog/COPERNICUS_S5P_NRTI_L3_NO2).

[A guide](https://atmosphere.copernicus.eu/flawed-estimates-effects-lockdown-measures-air-quality-satellite-observations) from Copernicus states that there are "quality flags related to the presence of clouds within each pixel: 0% pixels means that the sky above this particular area is free of clouds and, conversely, 100% means that the entire sky is covered by clouds." There are many cloud related S-5P parameters on p140 of [the documentation](https://sentinel.esa.int/documents/247904/2474726/Sentinel-5P-Level-2-Product-User-Manual-Nitrogen-Dioxide)

How can I filter by the quality flag mentioned using earth engine?

With [Landsat data](https://developers.google.com/earth-engine/image_info) you can view the cloud property like this

```
// Get a specific metadata property.
var cloudiness = image.get('CLOUD_COVER');
print('CLOUD_COVER: ', cloudiness); // ee.Number
```

I've tried viewing the metadata properties of S-5P like this, but the properties returned are only high-level

```
// Get a list of all metadata properties.
var properties = collection.propertyNames();
print('Metadata properties: ', properties); // ee.List of metadata properties
```

I've also looked at [the earth engine page](https://developers.google.com/earth-engine/datasets/catalog/COPERNICUS_S5P_NRTI_L3_NO2) Image Properties tab however those don't seem to relate to Quality or Cloud cover

Here is the basic code

```
var collection = ee.ImageCollection('COPERNICUS/S5P/NRTI/L3_NO2')
  .select('tropospheric_NO2_column_number_density')
  .filterBounds(geometry)

var current = collection.filterDate('2019-03-20', '2019-03-27').mean();

var vizParams = { min: 0, max: 0.0002, palette: ['black', 'red']};
Map.addLayer(current, vizParams, 'S5P N02');
```

**UPDATE**

I haven't been able to find any of the references to cloud within the NO2 data, however [S-5P](https://developers.google.com/earth-engine/datasets/catalog/COPERNICUS_S5P_NRTI_L3_NO2) has a "cloud_fraction" band. I am able to set this to 5% and [apply it as a mask](https://developers.google.com/earth-engine/getstarted#masking) to the NO2 dataset. Is this the correct way to get my result?

```
// Cloud mask for pixels with less than 5% cloud cover
var cloudMask = function(image) {
      return image.updateMask(image.select("cloud_fraction").lt(5));
    };

// Map the cloud masking functions over NO2 data
var collection = ee.ImageCollection('COPERNICUS/S5P/NRTI/L3_NO2')
  .select(['tropospheric_NO2_column_number_density','cloud_fraction'])
  .filterDate('2019-03-01', '2019-03-28')
  .filterBounds(geometry)
  .map(cloudMask);

// Reduce the collection to the mean of each pixel and display.
var meanImage = collection.reduce(ee.Reducer.mean());
var vizParams = {min: 0, max: 0.0002};
Map.addLayer(meanImage, vizParams, 'S5P N02 mean');
```

Answer (score 3):

The script seems fine to me, but I think you should correct the mask value: in S5P, cloud_fraction range is [0, 1] so you should mask with lt(0.05) rather than lt(5)